# API call to upload Graph Stylesheet file to Neo4J

Tags: api, neo4j

using Graph Stylesheets in Neo4J is nice, but I don't like the manual upload procedure.

Is there any way to perform that upload with the Neo4J API?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, it's stored in the browser in local storage.

[image: Neo4j Browser Storage]

And right now there is no functionality to tie it to the database.

It should be possible to create e.g. a chrome extension that allows management of grass files, history etc. But I'm not knowledgable enough to know how to tie it in.